# C# & SQL Server Insert ExecuteNonQuery: which column is causing the error "String or Binary Data Would Be Truncated?"

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, truncated, executenonquery

I'm trying to insert into a table in a C# program. I have this insert command:

```
var insertSql = @"INSERT INTO dbo.[Case]
                  VALUES (@Id, @IsDeleted, @CaseNumber, @ContactId, @AccountId, @ParentId, @SuppliedName, @SuppliedEmail, @SuppliedPhone, @SuppliedCompany, @Type, @RecordTypeId, @Status, @Reason, @Origin...
```

And then I've got many lines adding in the parameters like so:

```
var command = new SqlCommand(insertSql, easySoftConn);

if (case2.Id != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", case2.Id);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", DBNull.Value);

if (case2.IsDeleted != null)
{
    if (case2.IsDeleted == "true")
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", 1);
    else
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", 0);
}
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDeleted", DBNull.Value);

if (case2.CaseNumber != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseNumber", case2.CaseNumber);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseNumber", DBNull.Value);

if (case2.ContactId != null)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactId", case2.ContactId);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactId", DBNull.Value);       
...
```

When I finally execute the insert:

```
try
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
{
    CLog.Write(e.Message.ToString(), CLog.ErrLvl.Error);...
}
```

I get the error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

My issue is, the error doesn't tell me *which* column would be truncated. I've got 80 columns I'm inserting into, and I'd rather not go through them one-by-one. Is there a way to get the error handling to tell me exactly which field is throwing the error?

**EDIT:** I have a full stack trace in my log file but it still doesn't tell me which column, I just shortened it to the actual error here.

Comment: Only with SQL Server **2019** has MS finally made this error message more meaningful, telling you what the "offending" column is. If you're not on 2019 - there won't be any other way than to start eliminating columns one by one - start with the shortest ones, those are most likely to cause the issue.

Comment: Worth also noting that using AddWithValue in SQLServer (but not necessarily other db) can cause performance issues with some types of queries; not so much with insert, but be wary of using in selects. Dan Guzman has an interesting write up about it at https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/ - if you're looking to switch your data access over to using strongly typed datasets you avoid this too because the generated code can makes fine grained control of inspecting the db column type and matching it locally rather than guessing from the local type (which is what AWV does )

Answer (score 2):

Switching to using strongly typed data access would head this one off sooner:

- Add a dataset file to your project
- Open it, right click the surface, add tableadapter, set connection parameters, add a query of `SELECT * FROM [Case]`
- FInish the wizard, a datatable and adapter are generated. The DB is used to drive the creation, so all the string columns have a MaxLength property in the dataset that comes from the DB
- Attempting to add a row to this table will now cause an error like "unable to set column XYZ, the value violates the MaxLength limit for the column"

Data access code looks like:

```
var dt = new YourDataSetNameHere.CaseDataTable();
dt.AddCaseRow(put, your, values, here, you , dont, need, to worry, about, null, this, or, data, type, that, because, VS, handles, it, all, for, you, in, the, DataSet.Designer.cs, file);

new YourDataSetNameHereTableAdapters.CaseTableAdapter().Update(dt); //save the new row;
```

So it'll save you a boatload of time writing boring data access code too

Comment: Well I think I got the dataset created correctly and called it CaseData, but I don't see an option to instantiate a new CaseDataTable (var dt = new CaseDataTable();). The closest is a new CaseData(), but there's no option on that for AddCaseRow or even just AddRow. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Figured it out, I need to instantiate it like var dt = new CaseData.CaseDataTable();

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I was AFK. Yep, you did good. All the classes have gone in a different namespace. Next time that happens and there's a wiggly red line under CaseDataTable, you can try click on the word and then a lightbulb appears in the margin. If you click on that C# will suggest some things like "change to CaseData.CaseDataTable", "add 'using CaseData' to top of file", "create new class called CaseDataTable"... you can click one to implement it 

Comment: The tableadapters are on another own namespace, something like *whateverYourDataSetIsCalled*TableAdapters, so you might need to using/specify that too.

Comment: Other tips I didn't cover; you can add multiple queries to a table adapter, so right click on it in the dataset, add a query, "select that returns rows", add something like maybe `select * from [case] where Id = @id` or `select * from [case] where caseworkername like @name`.. call them FillById / FillByName etc and then in your code you can just have a TableAdapter and say `ta.FillById(someCaseDatatable, 123)` or `ta.FillByName(someCaseDatatable, "John%")` and all the selecting and pulling of data is done for you..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL version you can apply a KB to get this to show more data as stated here - [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4468101-improvement-optional-replacement-for-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-with-extended-information-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-a4279ad6-1d3b-3960-77ef-c82a909f4b89)

It effectively starts to show messages like the following

> Msg 2628, Level 16, State 6, Procedure ProcedureName, Line Linenumber
> String or binary data would be truncated in table '%.*ls', column
> '%.*ls'. Truncated value: '%.*ls'.

This came from this great post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584678/how-to-solve-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-r-nthe-statement-has)  which goes much further to explain how you can try and search for the column should this not be possible. The post also talks about how you can do manual searching although I'd imagine if the list of columns is too large that may be something you want to avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately we're still on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value of one or more of your parameters has more length than the table cell can contain.
You should to look at table column definitions.